# Unable to add action bar items in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I've been searching for half an hour and none of the solutions for other people are working for me.

Here is what is shows in the preview to the right:

[image]

Here is the java code in my activity (I removed the other stuff):

```
public class PlayGame extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.play_game);

    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_playgame);
    myToolbar.setTitle("ChessClock");
    myToolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() { } //Back Button Disabled

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbaroverflow, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_pause:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Menu Item 1 selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

All the instructions said to make an XML in my 'menu' directory but I didn't have one so I made it (called 'menu' inside of 'res'). The XML 'actionbaroverflow' has this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_pause"

    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Pause"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

And the item is simply not showing up when I run the app. I had an icon but someone said it could have been too big, so I just made it text and it's still not showing up.

Comment: what you are saying is that you didnt have a menu folder inside your res directory?

Comment: well yeah I didn't so I made one, I thought it was weird so I mentioned it

Answer (score 0):

Tou need to add to your `R.menu.actionbaroverflow`

```
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
```

Will be something like this:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_pause"
    android:icon="@drawable/your_icon"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="Pause"
    app:showAsAction="always"/>
```

Comment: So you always need an icon if you want it to display in the action bar?

It worked by the way, the problem with my previous icon is I didn't put it in the correct mipmap resolution folder (I just put it in all of them)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me fine:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:activity=".ProductsNewOrder">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_pause"
        android:title="Pause"
        android:visible="true"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_pause"/>
</menu>
```

and in the activity:

```
setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);
if (myToolbar!= null) {
            myToolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                    int id = item.getItemId();
                    switch (id) {
                        case R.id.action_pause: {
                            //do something
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }
```

and where i inflate the menu:

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbaroverflow, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!